# Debug custom Multithreaded Cache

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I have an array of 32 cache objects and I am refreshing each of the cache periodically after every 20 seconds. Attached code snippet below.

I am observing that few caches stops refreshing after some refresh cycles and there is no exception printed in the logs. Note that application is not crashing, but some caches are not getting refreshed.

```
public class CacheManager
{

    private static class CacheRefresher extends Thread
    {
        Cache cache; 

        public CacheRefresher(Cache cache)
        {
            this(cache);
        }

        @Override
        public final void run()
        {

                try {
                    LOG.info("cache is getting refreshed for " + cache.type);
                    cache.refreshCache();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    String subject = "Cache refresh failed in BMW";
                    LOG.log(Level.WARN, subject + ". Exception thrown:", e);

                }
        }       
    }

    public void refreshCaches(List<cache> caches)
    {
        ThreadFactory ourThreadFactory =
                new NamedThreadFactory("CacheHandler", true);

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduleService =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(32, ourThreadFactory);
        initialDelay = 60;
        for (Cache cache : caches) {  
            service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new CacheRefresher(cache), initialDelay, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            initialDelay += 2;
            cacheContainers.add(cache);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible that a thread is exceeding max heap limit and error is getting thrown but since I am not catching error I am not observing it?

But I am not sure if outofmemory error is thrown by one thread then will the entire application stop or only a thread will get impacted? Any comment?

Comment: If your application goes out of heap space it'll crash the application completely so I don't think it is the heap size issue.

Comment: Out of memory is not an exception, it's an error. It should impact your whole application (ie all threads), but usually doesn't shut it down immediately.

Comment: Why your refresher is static class?

Comment: @yuanqingfei is there a problem if this is static?

Comment: Can you try by removing the static in the refresher class. You are creating a new object of that class 32 times but since you have specified it as static it will cause an issue.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal I am not very sure. Just feel strange. However, you should be very careful with `static` when deal with multiple threads.

Comment: Just to confirm, is it an actual application or home work? If the answer is  not homework, I will recommend standard solutions instead of creating your own. The one that I often use <https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained>. Also note that if you want a distributed cache i.e. available across app servers, you are looking at a different problem. Hope this comment helps.

Comment: Actually the same code was working fine when the cache refresh interval was 30 seconds. As soon I made it 20 sec things started breaking.

Comment: @AnupamSaini It is an already running app. I dont have much control over it, but thanks for suggestion

Comment: ok, if that is the case, Can you also paste the code of your Cache class, or at-least with sensitive parts removed?

Comment: thats actually a huge code, not possible to put it completely. It is basically loading data from file system to cache and publishing cache content to elastic search.

Comment: ok, Can you change the "CacheRefresher" class to implement just the "Runnable" interface. This will not fix your issue, but you don't want it to extend the thread.

Comment: I have created a quick testbed, let me know if this mirrors your use case. https://repl.it/@HenryChang2/SlushyCriticalInformationtechnology-2

Comment: It does, are u able to reproduce?

Comment: Nope without access to your code, I won't be. I created this test bed for you to validate that you are doing something similar

Comment: Notice in my code I have scheduled it to run for very large number of days. How is it run in your code? Is it part of a stand alone Java binary or a server process?